# attach an event listener when an item is moved to a particular folder Outlook VSTO

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

What I want to achieve is to attach an event listener when a user moves an item from any folders in Outlook(Inbox, spam, draft,etc) to a particular user-created folder("abc" for example).

At this stage I just want to show "Hello World" when the item is being move to folder "abc".

I know I probably can leverage the `Folder.BeforeItemMove` event, But the event is for when items are being moved from a particular folder, **And I want the event  when Items are moved into a particular folder.**

I tried `FolderChange`event too, it makes sense because it fires when things happen in a folder. But its event handler only comes with a `Folder` parameter, not something like `EventArgs` so I cannot distinguish the user action(whether add, move, delete etc)

My work around is to add the `Folder.BeforeItemMove` event to every folders except for "abc" using a loop in `ThisAddIn_Startup`.

```
foreach(Folder f in folders)
{
 f.BeforeItemMove += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolderEvents_12_BeforeItemMoveEventHandler(BeforeItemMove);
}
```

But it only work once, not through the whole life cycle. I know it is probably because I do not declare all the folder properties in the class level they get collected but how can I do that? If I only need to monitor say "inbox" I could do

```
Folder Inbox

private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Folderroot = (Folder)this.Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRootFolder();
        inbox = root.Folders["Inbox"];
        inbox.BeforeItemMove += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolderEvents_12_BeforeItemMoveEventHandler(BeforeItemMove);
    }
```

That way the "Inbox" folder will not be collected by GC. **But I dont know how to deal with the situation when multiples folders need to be monitored.**

Am I on the right track or there is a better solution?

Comment: "I tried FolderChangeevent too, but it fires on multiple events not just "move in"", to me this makes the most sense, and you could check the EventArgs object to see what it represents, if it is a file move do your logic, else just ignore it.

Comment: @RyanWilson that FolderChange event  handler does not seems to come with EventArgs parameter, it comes only with Folder parameter, with folder I could not distinguish the type of actions(move, rename, delete etc)

Comment: Couldn't you just track the Count of the folder and then if it changes, you can determine that some files have been moved into it?

Comment: @RyanWilson seems to be a right-on. I now declare a global count and check the local count against the global every time when items change fires, I also update it on delete and add. A bit tedious but it seems to work.

Comment: I took a brief view through the Outlook API documentation, that was the best I could come up with without much research. Glad it is working for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a wrapper class that takes an `Items` object and stores as a class member. Set up an `Items.ItemAdd` event handler for that object as a method in that wrapper class. In your addin, use a list of wrappers (`List<MyWrapper>)` to store wrappers for the Items collection of each folder that you want to monitor. These way the Items objects will be prevents from being Garbage Collected.

Comment: Do I monitor all the folders that the items are going to move out? Or just the "abc" folder that the items are going to move in? I am more inclined with the latter after reading the doc, but I think you are suggesting the formal?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean - do you mean **all** folders in a store vs only the folders where the message can be potentially moved? The latter is of course more efficient.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I mean all potential folders that the items can be possibly moved out(like inbox, spam, delete). Or can I just monitor the target folder(in my case "abc"?) that is the folder will receive the items from all other potential folders.I am not sure which way to go without much experiments, the doc is not too clear to me.

Comment: If the item can potentially be moved to any folder, it might be a better idea to avoid events completely and just periodically scan the folders to see if anything was added there.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are interested in the [ItemAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/items-itemadd-event-outlook) event of the Items class. It is fired when one or more items are added to the specified collection. This event does not run when a large number of items are added to the folder at once (more than sixteen).

You must subscribe to each folder/items separately in the code to get events for all folders.

Comment: no it works i move more then 500 items. and all get processed. o am using outlook 2013 addin though